# Images as planes loose quality when imported to the scene? | How do I make this simple animation?

Tags: animation, image-sequence

I want to do a simple animation of zooming to different pictures, the camera should be moving to focus on each image and then zoom out to see all images, But when I import Images as planes and render the scene the images loose a lot of quality. (unlike importing them straight to the compositor for example)

even if I use emission shader for the images and delete the lights in the scene and use orthographic camera it still looks bad.

In the compositor the images look great but it’s very clunky to do this type of animation from the compositor.

Any ideas please?

Comment: pls provide blend file, because you didn't tell us any settings you made, so we can check it out on our own. thx.

Comment: Maybe try to switch the Image Texture from Linear to Closest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heyo!
Are you trying to make a texture not be affected by lighting?

You can plug your texture straight into material output.
Also set interpolation to "closest" for a crisp-looking image.

[image]

Comment: Omg man thank you so much! pluging the image straight to the output solved it for me even without changing the interpolation mode!
I've never though about this simple solution lol.
Finally I can copy my after effects workflow to blender easily thank you so much! :)

Comment: @Cr0wnM3 Hello and welcome. This site is not a regular forum, please don't reply "Thanks" as an answer or comment, instead [upvote the post that helped you](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote). If you feel it completely solved your issue consider [marking it as accepted](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer).

Comment: You should note that this only works for EEVEE, not Cycles